# GSF400 Bandit carburetor model or type,

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki

I have  Suzuki Bandit GSF400 model '92.

May I know the type of carb do I have on it? I am trying to do some replacement on jets but I need sizes.

Answer (score 2):

The carb belongs to the [Mikuni BST series family](http://www.ebay.com/itm/SUZUKI-BANDIT-GSF400-600-1200-MIKUNI-BST-CARBURETOR-O-RING-REBUILD-KIT-/321852473311). Also see [this site](http://www.bikebandit.com/aftermarket-parts/motorcycle-fuel-and-air/1992-suzuki-bandit-400-gsf400-carb-kits-parts-accessories-universal/pb9?m=147864).